# After Creating a new List Item - Change view to the new item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer, guid

In SharePoint Designer, I'm creating a manual workflow that creates a new item in list 2 from list 1. I note that the "Create New List Item" does this well. It also returns the guid of the new item.  After creating the new item in list 2, I'd like the workflow to end with the user's browser pointing to the newly created item, not remaining on list 1.  How do I do this?

Succinctly, How can I redirect the user's browser to the GUID within a workflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to meet your requirement using workflow.

Consider using some code, as described below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ddb4740c-5d92-43e0-9ec5-a5f923c0a410/redirect-browser-after-completing-custom-list-item-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious